# c# typeof applied to generic parameter supertype

Tags: c#, generics, wildcard, typeof

I have a method, it doesn't have any T parameters.

Unfortunately, C# typeof operator doesnt work on generics as shown bellow.

```
public static string ToString(object obj)
{
    if (obj.GetType() == typeof(List<object>))
    {
        return "Bug: Never called";
    }
    if (obj.GetType() == typeof(List<int>))
    {
        return "Method only works for int lists";
    }
    return "";
}
```

Expected output: ToString(List of ints) would return "Bug: Never Called".

Actual output: "Method only works for int lists"

This worked perfectly fine in Java. You will say that generics in c# don't support this. How can I restructure my code to make "ToString(object)" method work for a list of objects?

Requirements : You cannot modify the method's signature, only its implementation.

Unfortunately you cannot make "int" class implement an interface. Since int class was written by Microsoft. As such I cannot add a visitor pattern on int type.

Comment: Why do you expect a `List<int>` return "Bug: Never Called" which is the branch for `List<object>`?

Comment: I don't understand why you expect the type of a `List<int>` object to be `List<object>`. Yea that's what Java does, but C# is not Java. Arguably, the behavior of Java is not what most people expect. I guess you could use GetGenericTypeDefintion and compare to `typeof(List<>)` to see if it is a list of something.

Comment: Because object is the superclass of int. i thought object "captures" int as well.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer - `object` **is** the super class of `int`.

Comment: @user2186597 - Just because `int` derives from `object` it doesn't mean that `List<int>` derives from `List<object>`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Unfortunately, c# typeof operator doesn't work on generics as shown bellow.

Actually, it's quite fortunate that it doesn't work as you expect it to work. Unlike Java, C# differentiates between `List<int>` and `List<object>` at runtime, not only at compile time. Type information for generics instantiated with primitive type parameters lets .NET produce more efficient code by avoiding type erasure.

If you would like to test if an object is *any* generic list, use this check instead:

```
var objT = obj.GetType();
if (objT.IsGenericType && objT.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(List<>)) {
    ...
}
```

> As such I cannot add a visitor pattern on `int` type.

C# gives you a powerful mechanism for dispatching dynamically without implementing an interface. For example, you can do this:

```
public static string ToString(object obj) {
    var list = obj as IList;
    if (list != null) {
        foreach (dynamic o in list) {
            Process(o);
        }
    }
}
static void Process(int n) { ... }
static void Process(string s) { ... }
static void Process(object o) { ... }
```

The above will choose the right implementation of `Process` based on the run-time type of the object in your list.

Comment: Great, you answered the first part of the question, why doesnt c# generics work that way. Now for the second part of question : i only want to manipulate the list uniformly regardless of the underlying type.

Comment: Any generic **list** :D

Comment: dasblinkenlight, thats nice, but casting will throw an exception if the underlying object is not a list. Thats why i focused on the "if condition".